# Error when trying to bake light map using SceneKit

Tags: xcode, scenekit, collada

I have a `.dae` model, converted to a `.scn` scene. I have added a static light source. But when I'm trying to bake light map to a texture, I get the error message:

> **An error occured while baking light maps.** Failed to bake lightmap for mesh […]

[image]

Any ideas what might cause this? Could the vertex count be too high?

Comment: Install Xcode 10.1, there is possibly a bug in Xcode10.0

Comment: @ARGeo Yes, I installed it earlier. Unfortunately it didn't resolve this issue.

Comment: Then, what's your code?

Comment: @ARGeo Not using any code yet. This is through the SceneKit editor gui. All I'm doing is importing .dae file, adding diffuse and rougness texture, adding static light source, and pressing "Bake" button to bake light map to texture. Then the error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried baking a number of times in Xcode 10 and I can say it works fine if your geometry is fine. I successfully baked 2Kx2K textures for models with 300K polygons.

An error may occur when your `.dae` geometry has one of the following issues:

- Non-planar faces
- Faces with more than four sides
- Lamina faces
- Non-manifold geometry
- Edges with a zero length
- Faces with zero geometry area
- Faces with a zero map area
- Concave faces
- Faces with holes

**Solution: clean up your model in 3D authoring application before exporting it to `.dae`**.

For example, in [Autodesk Maya](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Mesh--Cleanup-htm.html) this option is accessible via main menu `Mesh` > `Cleanup`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This was it. The problem was that the meshes wasn't triangulated. It now works! Weird that Xcode doesn't do that on import, or have a better error message.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.